# FirebaseAnimatedList change content in real time

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I'd like to know how to rebuild the FirebaseAnimatedList with a new query, new content changing the path.

```
new Flexible(
              child: new FirebaseAnimatedList(
                  query: query,
                  sort: (DataSnapshot a, DataSnapshot b) =>
                      b.key.compareTo(a.key),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
                      Animation<double> animation, int index) {...})
```

When i change the query in realtime it not changes the result in the list:

```
setState(() {
  query = "another/path";
});
```

Comment: I have asked a question that could be similar, I hope someone can help us. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52646592/flutter-firebase-how-to-change-the-query-and-the-content

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it working changing the Key each time i change the query, i not sure if is the best way, but is working:

```
new Flexible(
              child: new FirebaseAnimatedList(
                  key: _key,
                  query: query,
                  sort: (DataSnapshot a, DataSnapshot b) =>
                      b.key.compareTo(a.key),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
                      Animation<double> animation, int index) {...})


setState(() {
  query = "another/path";
  _key = Key('anotherkey');
});
```

Comment: tip: _key = Key(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString());